# Unequal UV wrapping

Tags: vertices, uv-image-editor, vertex-groups

[image]I made a perfect cylindrical shape and wanted to add this texture. After unwrapping it...the wrap is uneven and distorted. How does this happen and how can I fix it without moving the vertices individually?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you show the cylinder in edit mode?

Comment: There's [UVsquares addon](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-uvsquares-v1-9-updated-2-80-and-multi-island-support/613111) which tries to address this issue

Answer (score 2):

UV Editing / Unwrapping might come in handy.
You seem to have unwrapped the cylinder from view.

The simplest thing to do is to add seams.

In Edit Mode, select vertices as seams then press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

[image: Select vertices and mark seams]

Then after you are done simply hit <kbd>U</kbd>->Unwrap and you will have a perfectly balanced unwrap

[image: Unwrapped Cylinder]

Comment: Thank you for answering! Actually yes I did mark all the necessary seams. Seems when I unwrap it I get this curve at the top and bottom of the can.     https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcUHg.jpg

Answer (score 2):

the length of rings is different, the topmost selected edge loop on this image is shorter than lower edge loops:

[image]

So Blender makes the bottom edge (left on UV map) loop have maximum length on the texture, the top (right on UV map), shorter edge to have proportionally smaller length on the texture, and interpolates between them, gradually decreasing each edge's length for a smooth transition.

I wish I knew of a method to mark faces which aren't supposed to be stretched, so Blender starts the transition later, but I don't. I can recommend either using seams in this fashion, to simulate cutting an unstretchable label so it can fit to a can (not sure how often a technology like this is actually used in reality):

[image]

Or alternatively, you could create two *Shape Keys* (in *Object Mode*):

[image]

With *Key 1* selected as on the GIF above, enter the edit mode. Set *Snapping* to *Vertex* and make sure it's enabled for scaling:

[image]

For each edge loop, select it be <kbd>ALT</kbd>-clicking a horizontal edge, press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to not scale vertically, and snap to a vertex of *the longest edge loop*:

[image]

**Unwrap** your mesh, exit *Edit Mode*, and remove your *Shape Keys* (or just select the base key to edit it from now on, while leaving the Key 1 if you need to e.g. unwrap again)